# Set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true on storage.googleapis.com?

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to set CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true` on my storage.googleapis.com bucket. The reason is that I don't have control over the XHR parameters in which `whithCredentials=true`.

I'm able to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header properly but I can't find any mention about the specific header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` in Google Cloud Storage doc.

```
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-cors
```

Do you know whether it is possible and how to do it?

Comment: Is there any reason why this question is downvoted ??! cause I had the exact same problem ... the person who downvoted this .. enlight me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you can configure your bucket to support [CORS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin), however, at the moment, in Google Cloud Storage(GCS), you can only [set some metadata fields](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#settable-fields-field-values) such as Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-Language, Content-Language and Custom metadata.

You might want to [open](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui) a feature request in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) for this.

As a possible workaround, you might want to use any of the [access controls options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/) available for GCS